# CSS div display not working

Tags: css, hover, zurb-foundation-5

I want the div `#aboutBlurb` to appear on `#aboutLink:hover`. I am using Foundation 5.2's grid system if that is of any relevance. Here is my code:

```
  <div id="navBar">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-3 columns">
     <a href="#about" class="circleLink" id="aboutLink"><span>About</span></a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="aboutBlurb"><h3>blah</h3></div>   
  </div>



#navBar a.circleLink:hover
{
    background-color: #bc2029;
    color:white;
}
#aboutBlurb
{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    display:none;
}
#navBar #aboutLink:hover + #aboutBlurb
{
    display:block;
}
```

I have tried using the `~` and `>` selectors as well as no selector also.

Comment: `+` and `~` don’t work in the parent element direction. You have to use JavaScript here.

Comment: is there any way to rearrange my code so I can use `~` or `+`? I'd rather use JavaScript as a last resort.

Comment: I can’t see any possibility… CSS-wise the two elements are simply too far apart.

Comment: if you really want to do it with css, you could position the element absolutely ... lol. My point is, what you are trying to do is on the interaction side, so it's ok to use JavaScript.

Comment: If you are able to rearrange your code, sure. Just put #aboutBlurb right after the #aboutlink.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a CSS answer, but doing this with JavaScript is fairly easy. If you have jQuery installed just add this line:

```
$( "#aboutLink" ).hover(function() {
  $( '#aboutBlurb' ).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this need to change your DOM order please check this

```css
#navBar a.circleLink:hover
{
    background-color: #bc2029;
    color:white;
}
#aboutBlurb
{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width:80%;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: red;
    display: none;
}
#aboutLink:hover + #aboutBlurb
{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="navBar">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-3 columns">
     <a href="#about" class="circleLink" id="aboutLink"><span>About</span></a>
     <div id="aboutBlurb"><h3>blah</h3></div>  
    </div>
   </div>   
  </div>
```